# Sails.js -- Accessing local.js environment settings in controllers

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

In **production** I have AWS credentials stored as heroku config variables.

In **development** I want to include the config details in config/local.js, but *how do I access the config details in a controller?*

local.js contains:

`module.exports = {
  aws_key: "...", aws_secret: "..."
}`

In my controller I have tried `aws_key`, `config.aws_key`, and others - but no luck. Is there a main app namespace that I can use to scope into the properties exported by local.js?

I am new to sails and I feel like this should be straight forward - any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Solution found. Step 3 was where I was having trouble.**

## tl;dr

**What I didn't realize** was that the `module.exports.thing` makes the `thing` object available through `sails.config.thing`. Good to know.

---

**1)** I created a new file at config/aws.js with the contents

```
// Get heroku config values     
module.exports.aws = {
  key: process.env.AWS_KEY,
  secret: process.env.AWS_SECRET
}
```

**2)** In local.js put the actual AWS creds (this won't end up in the repository since sails automatically ignores local.js using gitignore).

```
aws: {
  key: actual-key,
  secret: actual-secret
}
```

This allows for local testing where we don't have access to the heroku config settings, while protecting these values from being exposed in a github repo.

**3)** Now, to access in the controller:

```
var aws_config = sails.config.aws;

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: aws_config.key,
  secretAccessKey: aws_config.secret
});
```

---

Comment: Here how can we use different config for different environments like dev/production.