# read variables from local.js file in sails.js :undefined variable error

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Refer from this question [Sails.js -- Accessing local.js environment settings in controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291111/sails-js-accessing-local-js-environment-settings-in-controllers) i am trying to get config values from

Here is my current configurations

`config/local.js`

```
aws: {
        key: 'MY KEY',
        secret: 'MY VALUE'
    }
```

in `config/params.js`

```
module.exports.params = {

    key: process.env.AWS_KEY,
    secret: process.env.AWS_SECRET

}
```

But when i log   `console.log(sails.config.params.key)` i got undefined error

Answer (score 1):

Its simple it can be simply accessed by `sails.config.aws.key`

`local.js`

```
aws: {
        key: 'MY KEY',
        secret: 'MY VALUE'
    }
```